# OpenTelemetry Collector not exporting data to Azure Data Explorer

Tags: c++, grpc, azure-data-explorer, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm currently facing issues with sending telemetry data from a C++ desktop application to Azure, specifically Azure Data Explorer.

In my project, telemetry is being sent via a gRPC exporter to a collector on the same machine. This collector successfully writes the telemetry data to local files. However, when attempting to send the data to Azure, I find that no data appears in the Azure Data Explorer (ADX) tables that I have set up.

I haven't noticed any error messages from the collector, which makes the issue even harder to troubleshoot. As a reference, I've been following the steps laid out in the Azure documentation for creating an Azure Active Directory application registration in Azure Data Explorer ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/provision-azure-ad-app)).

To help identify if there is any configuration issue, I have attached the OpenTelemetry (otel) collector YAML file (`otel-collector.yml`) here.

I'm at a bit of a loss for how to proceed with debugging this issue. If anyone could provide some guidance, or even better, a working example that I could compare to, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

otel-collector.yml:

```
receivers:
    otlp: # the OTLP receiver the app is sending traces to
      protocols:
        grpc:
  
  exporters:
    azuredataexplorer:
      cluster_uri: "https://<adx-clustor-name>.<region>.kusto.windows.net"
      application_id: "<app_id>"
      application_key: "<app-key>"
      tenant_id: "<tenent-id>"
      db_name: "MyDatabase"
      metrics_table_name: "OTMetrics"
      logs_table_name: "OTLogs"
      traces_table_name: "OTTraces"
      ingestion_type : "managed"
    logging:
      #logLevel: info
    file: # the File Exporter, to ingest logs to local file
      path: "./app_example.json"
      rotation:
  
  processors:
    batch:
  
  service:
    pipelines:
      traces:
        receivers: [otlp]
        processors: [batch]
        exporters: [file, azuredataexplorer]
      metrics:
        receivers: [otlp]
        processors: [batch]
        exporters: [file, azuredataexplorer]
      logs:
        receivers: [otlp]
        processors: [batch]
        exporters: [file, azuredataexplorer]
```

Otel Collector output:

```
C:\otel-collector>otelcol-contrib.exe  --config=C:\otel-collector\otel-collector-config.yaml
2023-06-06T12:00:07.889-0700    info    service/telemetry.go:113        Setting up own telemetry...
2023-06-06T12:00:07.890-0700    info    service/telemetry.go:136        Serving Prometheus metrics      {"address": ":8888", "level": "Basic"}
2023-06-06T12:00:07.891-0700    info    service/service.go:141  Starting otelcol-contrib...     {"Version": "0.77.0", "NumCPU": 32}
2023-06-06T12:00:07.891-0700    info    extensions/extensions.go:41     Starting extensions...
2023-06-06T12:00:07.891-0700    warn    internal/warning.go:51  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks        {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-06-06T12:00:07.892-0700    info    otlpreceiver@v0.77.0/otlp.go:94 Starting GRPC server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4317"}
2023-06-06T12:00:07.892-0700    info    service/service.go:158  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
```

Comment: Hello shivi, can you attach the full logs for this? The exporter seems to be shutdown because of the whole set up getting shutdown? . If there are any logs you can attach it will be very helpful to go further

Comment: Since you are using managed ingestion_type, please make sure you have streaming ingestion enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-streaming?tabs=azure-portal%2Ccsharp
`.alter table <table> policy streamingingestion enable`

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G hey sorry I killed the process so that's why it shows the shutdown logs. I have attached logs where I left it running.

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn thanks for the suggestion! I did double check that I had `streamingingestion` enabled on all the tables.

Comment: I got it working finally.
So previously, I was using an existing cluster I had created in https://dataexplorer.azure.com/freecluster and followed the steps 1-7 described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/provision-azure-ad-app - this did NOT work and I don't know exactly why.
This time around I created a new ADX cluster from the Azure portal -> Create a resource, followed the rest of the steps and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

"However, when attempting to send the data to Azure, I find that no data appears in the Azure Data Explorer (ADX) tables that I have set up."

from the log you attached i see that the azure service process appears to start correctly and is ready to start processing your data.  then something called otelcol/collector receives an interrupt signal from the OS as soon as it starts processing your data, followed by the azure service shutting down.

i do see a warning about using address 0.0.0.0 because it is unsafe.  this could be the collector refusing to function because of that.  the collector also may have some configuration issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).